# CSS - Responsive grid with equal margins and fixed size blocks

Tags: html, responsive-design, grid-layout, css

I'm trying to push the limits of CSS to replicate what would be a common grid-layout in print.

Requirements :

1. Margins between blocks and between blocks and edge of the container must be equal.
2. The layout must be responsive and the number of blocks on each row must adapt to the size of the window.
3. The last row must be left aligned
4. the width/height of the blocks is fixed
5. no use of empty non-semantic HTML elements
6. pure CSS solution, no JS

So, I have markup that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
       <span>Introduction and Curriculum</span>
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
       <span>Equipment and Workspace Prep</span>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

**Here is a mock-up of what I'm going for.**

[image: grid layout with equal margins]

Comment: is this the kind of layout you are trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/KrA6M/

Comment: Sort of? Here is an interactive version of what I'm going for. http://codepen.io/norbauer/pen/bLCpa Unfortunately, it uses a hack that requires inserting empty `<li>` elements, which I need to avoid. I am considering inserting them via JS, but I would first like to know if what I'm proposing is possible via more conventional CSS. The code proposed in that JSFiddle is even more obtuse. :) (though it does at least have the advantage of leaving the DOM alone.)

Comment: Have you already tried floats and `nth-child` for clearing + margin fixes? Those can be changed at different breakpoints.

Comment: Floats and fixes are things I want to avoid (I consider floats to be properly used for floating images within blocks of text only, not larger-scale layout.) I should perhaps clarify that the point of my question is to see whether there is a proper elegant approach to this in CSS. I don't care about just getting it done, as I know a number of easy hacks (such as adding dummy empty list items with a particular width and using flexbox.) I'm just trying to learn CSS best-practices here.

Comment: You can also take a look at these 2 answers for a grids with close requirements : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23803215/1811992 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *CSS* [calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Although it won't prevent from using media queries, It can **calculate the margin between elements and container** edges.

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/Hrchg)

This demo uses :

1. **calc()** CSS function. In this context, it will be supported by IE9+. You might want to add the `-webkit-` prefix for some webkit browsers. for more info, see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/calc).
2. **4 media queries** to change the number of elements displayed in one row and the margins accordingly.
3. **inline-block** elements. This involves dealing with the white space (in the demo I used the font-size technique but you may use an other one, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/5078297#5078297)).

---

### Explanation :

**Media query break points :**

They are calculated according to the width of the elements. As each element is `200px` wide I should have chosen break points at `screen width = 400px/600px/800px/1000px` but as media queries include the scrollbar, with those values, the elements would not have enough space and overlap each other.

Scrollbars don't have the same width on each browser so I chose a higher value to be sure that the overlapping doesn't occur.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/48jjx/1/) of this behaviour with "logical" media query break points.

**Margin calculation :**

First of all percent margins and padding are always calculated according to the remaining width of the container ([exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23754080/1811992)) so the top and bottom margins / paddings have the same calculation as the left/right ones.

Basically, the calculation of the size of margins is :

```
(remaining width (=100%) - the sum of grid elements width) / number of gaps
```

**But**

Left and top gaps are padding from the container and the other gaps are margin right and bottom on the block element. The margin calculation for the blocks must take that into account and the division is by the `number of gaps -1`.

---

*HTML :*

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="block">...</li>
    <li class="block">...</li>
    ...
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#container{
    font-size:0;    
    padding-top: calc((100% - 1000px)/6);
    padding-left:calc((100% - 1000px)/6);}

.block {
    font-size:20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: calc((100% - 1000px)/5);
    margin-bottom: calc((100% - 1000px)/5);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 430px) {
    .block {
        margin: calc(50% - 100px);
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 431px) and (max-width: 630px) {
    #container{
        padding-top: calc((100% - 400px)/3);
        padding-left:calc((100% - 400px)/3);
    }
    .block {
        margin-right: calc((100% - 400px)/2);
        margin-bottom: calc((100% - 400px)/2);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 631px) and (max-width: 830px) {
    #container{
        padding-top: calc((100% - 600px)/4);
        padding-left:calc((100% - 600px)/4);
    }
    .block {
        margin-right: calc((100% - 600px)/3);
        margin-bottom: calc((100% - 600px)/3);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 831px) and (max-width: 1030px) {
    #container{
        padding-top: calc((100% - 800px)/5);
        padding-left:calc((100% - 800px)/5);
    }
    .block {
        margin-right: calc((100% - 800px)/4);
        margin-bottom: calc((100% - 800px)/4);
    }
}
```

Comment: I may make some tweaks to this for what I finally use, but this is a very creative solution, and most appreciated. It's pure CSS and involves nothing that (to me, at least) feels like hackery. Well done.

Comment: One thing that might be helpful, by the way, is if you could explain where your numbers come from, and why you chose the media query breakpoints you did. thx again.

Comment: @RyanNorbauer you will have to tweak this solution according to the size of your elements and container. I will edit my question to include more explanation. Do you mind if I also drasticaly edit your question to make it more generic and easier to find for other users?

Comment: By all means. :) The purpose of asking the question was so I and others can learn CSS better, not just to solve a particular problem in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Nth-child and implementation at the respective breakpoints would probably be the best practice  method and the most lightweight solution.

There are a few other options such as 
1. Measuring screen width with jQuery and assigning styles at those different breakpoints
2. Assigning a class to the container using negative margins, so you wouldn't need to touch the actual margins

...etc.