# What does % height in css mean

Tags: css, height, percentage

I have a div whose child p tag contains text.

I want the `p` tag to only be `70%` in height.

This works, it is only `70%` of the parent's height. I then use "`overflow: hidden;`" on the p tag to hide the extra content.

Then I thought I could just add 15% `margin-top` or add 15% `padding-top` (to the parent) to vertically center the p tag in the parent div... but I find I need to set it to something like `3%`.... how come?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? There seems to be so many conflicting ideas here, making it hard to decide what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then I thought I could just add 15% margin-top or add 15% padding-top
>   (to the parent) to vertically center the p tag in the div... but I
>   find I need to set it to something like 3%.... how come?

Because percent margins and paddings (top, right, bottom and left) are calculated [according to the containing blocks width.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding#Values)

Top and bottom margins aren't calculated according to the parent's height so that is why 15% `margin-top` isn't 15% of the container height but 15% of container width.

**Workaround :**

You may use absolute or relative positioning as the parent has a fixed height and the top value in percent is calculated according to the parent's height so `top:15%;` will be 15% of the parent's height.

Comment: I think you mean *container height* ;)

Comment: @jbutler483 no all percent margins and paddings are calculated according to **paren'ts width** [see the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... what idiot decided it should be based on the width??? that is stupid!

Comment: @web-tiki: I didn't actually know that :3. Mind you, I don't really use margins much (more positioning/pseudo elements instead). So cheers for that :)

Comment: @RISCOS3 I don't know who decided that but it does allow to keep a [fixed aspect ratio for an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-a-way-to-maintain-aspect-ratio-when-resizing-a-div).

Comment: @jbutler483 note that there are some exceptions like in [flexbox layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717953/padding-bottom-top-not-working-in-flexbox-layout-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

You could use positioning in order to achieve this. So rather than setting the height of the p element, allow the positioning to do that for you (by adding `bottom: 15%;` and `top:15%;`). This would leve you with 70% content (as desired, I believe):

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  background:yellow; 
  position:relative;
  
}

p{
  position:absolute;  
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  top:15%;
  bottom:15%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p. i'm a long p.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... you and web-tiki have both been helpfull ;)

Comment: @RISCOS3: Web-tiki knew the reasoning behind it, I stuck with what I knew (which was, a 'work around'). So all in all, I think Web-tiki deserves that green tick.