# Flex inside flex doesent work in Firefox 38

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I try to use `flex` in firefox, it doesent work, in Chrome, it works like a charm!
Here is the result in Firefox:
[image]

And here is how it looks (should look) in Chrome/Opera:
[image]

What is the problem?

Here is the CSS, that doesent work on Firefox:

```
.jawcontain {display: flex;flex-direction: column;justify-content: space-between;border: white solid 7px;border-radius: 23px;}

.jaw {background-color: rgb(24, 24, 24);border-radius: 5%;display: flex;flex-direction: row;padding-top: 2%;padding-bottom: 5%;border: 10px solid rgb(0, 151, 255);justify-content: space-around;}

.hala {border: white solid 2px;padding-left: 10%;border-radius: 5%;margin-right: 2% display: flex;flex-basis: 40%;flex-direction: column;background: black;justify-content: space-around;}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I have added the CSS that makes the problem

Comment: @Abdelouahab That CSS is not enough. We need the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oriol I am sorry, because the code is generated from serveur side, here is the result http://meteo-algeria.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding-bottom/top not working in flexbox layout (Firefox)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23717953/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.jaw` are flex items, and you use

```css
.jaw {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
```

In CSS 2.1, percentages in [`padding`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties) were specified as

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the *width* of the
>   generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block), even for ['padding-top](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-padding-top)' and ['padding-bottom'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-padding-bottom).

However, in [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#item-margins),

> Percentage margins and paddings on [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) are always resolved
>   against their respective dimensions; unlike blocks, they do not always
>   resolve against the inline dimension of their containing block.

Therefore, Firefox attempts to resolve those percentages with respect to the *height* of the flex container. But that height is `auto`, that is, it depends on the height of the content, including the vertical paddings. It's a circular definition, so the paddings compute to `0`.

But Chrome does not agree, and resolves the percentages with respect to the width of the flex container. The spec warns about that:

> Note: This behavior is [currently disputed](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Mar/0273.html), and might change in a
>   future version of this specification to match the behavior of blocks.

Since you don't seem to be using flex, you can remove

```css
.jawcontain {
  display: flex;
}
```

Then, `.jaw` will no longer be flex items, and the paddings will be resolved with respect to the width of the containing block.

Comment: wow! dident knew that firefox hated so much the percentage! thank you again! I will remake the whole website using `px` instead of `%` Thank you again!