# How is padding calculated when using percentage (%)?

Tags: css, padding, box-sizing

**Why does the padding in this example not equal 300px?**

```css
#Test{
  width:600px;
  padding-right:50%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="Test">
TEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ H
</div>
```

- Where is the browser deriving it's calculation, 50% of what?
- In the example below the padding actually becomes smaller as the container of `#Test` becomes larger.
- I actually want the width of `#Test` to be dynamic however I've fixed it for the purpose of this example.
- And  how do I get 50% padding of `#Test`?

***Notes:*** I am not just looking for a solution but an understanding of the way padding is working here.

Comment: `50%` is a relative measurement. the question you should be asking is what that measurement is relative **TO**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ### TL;DR
>
> The padding is calculated according to the parent's width

---

First, you should note that:

> **Percentage**:
>   The percentage is calculated with respect to **the width of the generated box's containing block** [...] (*source: [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties), emphasis mine*)

This means the padding is calculated according to the **parent element width** (*it's worth to note that in [non flexbox layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717953/padding-bottom-top-in-flexbox-layout), padding top and bottom are also relative to the width of the containing block*).

### With box-sizing: border-box

When you change the default [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) to [border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Values), the padding (and border) is included in the width of the element like in your example. So with

```
width:600px;
padding-right:50%;
box-sizing:border-box;
```

The right padding must be 50% of parent's width but the overall width of element is 600px wide. The only moment the padding right is 50% of element's width is when `parent width = element width` (*Note that this can't happen in your example because the parent is body and body has a default margin*).

**Workaround:**
If you want the padding to be 50% of the element's width, in this box model you can:

- set a fixed padding: `width:600px; padding-right: 300px;`
- give the element a fluid width : `width:50%; padding-right:25%;`

---

### Without box-sizing: border-box

In the default box-model, the padding isn't included in the width of the element so `element width = 600px + 50% of parent's width` as you can see in the following example:

```css
#Test{
  width:600px;
  padding-right:50%;
  background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="Test">
TEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ HTEXT ETISI DHOASIHD I SAIDUHSILAUDH LISH ADBHSJADB JHSA DKH ASKDH KSAH DKLJS ADLK ASJKLD KLASH DLSJAH KLS ADKL S JS KSH KD KSJ HDKJSH DKH SDKH SKDH KSJH DKJSH DKJ H
</div>
```

**Workaround:**
If you want the padding to be 50% of the element's width, in this box model you can:

- set a fixed padding: `width:300px; padding-right: 300px;`
- give the element a fluid width : `width:25%; padding-right:25%;`

---

**References:**

- The box model [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html)
- The padding property : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding), [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#padding-properties)
- The box-sizing property : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#box-sizing)

Comment: With this in mind how do you create a desired percentage width for an element?

Comment: @Obsidian well in your case, it's pretty simple as you have a fixed width in px, you can give the padding a px value too, example : `padding-right:300px;`

Comment: :) and on a dynamic element I assume I would have to include an additional nested div?

Comment: @Obsidian you can do that or, if you want the element to have 50% width and have a padding equal to 50% of i's width, you can give padding a value of 25% because `50 / 2 = 25` .

Comment: @Josh Crozier: don't link to REC-CSS2 - that's the 1998 spec and some sections contain differences from CSS2.1.

Comment: Thx for pointing that out @BoltClock I also changed the links and references in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's in relation to the parent element's width, unless the parent's width depends on this one.

From W3C's [CSS 2.1 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.