# IMG generates scrollbars despite percentual width assignments

Tags: html, css

In [How is padding calculated when using percentage (%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748285/how-is-padding-calculated-when-using-percentage) was stated, that `padding` is calculated according to parent's width.

I now have the following assignment CSS-Code

```
.img_tutorial_full_width
{
    background-color : #3E3E42;

    margin           : 0;
    border           : 0;
    padding          : 1%;

    width            : 99%;
}
```

which I would expect, when applied to an `<img>`-Tag like this:

```
<img class="img_tutorial_full_width" src="../img/example.jpg"></img>
```

to stretch the container over the whole width, since

`margin=border := 0 + padding := 1% + content := 99% = 100%`

However, the browser shows scrollbars, that are increasing, the wider the window is. Where is the conceptual mistake?

Comment: img is a self-closing tag, for starters. You would use either `<img src="">` or `<img src="" />`.

Comment: @TiesonT. Thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, changing the code did not change the appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 100% Total Width. `padding: 1%;` takes 1% on the left and 1% on the right, so 2% in total

```
.img_tutorial_full_width
{
    background-color : #3E3E42;

    margin           : 0;
    border           : 0;
    padding          : 1%;

    width            : 98%;
}
```

works, because `98% + 2 * 1% = 100%`

Answer (score 0):

By default images are inline element. Inline elements ignores height and width properties. Just add `display: block;` or `display: inline-block` to the `.img_tutorial_full_width` class and it should work just fine.

Also please note, the `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` can be applied, but these have no effects on the inline elements. For detail explanation, you can [read this article](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. That is all true, but not the solution to the problem