# Controlling size of a HTML element at fixed aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, css

None of the answers I've looked up quite works for my use case.

I want to fix the aspect ratio of a HTML element on my page (specifically, a canvas which I want to always be square) in such a way that

- it's as large as fits in the alloted space;
- it fits inside the browser window without scrolling.

I don't think this can be done by CSS alone (please prove me wrong). I did find various CSS tricks purported to do it, but they take into account only either the available width or the available height, not both.

I tried javascript that looks up the size (`.parentElement.clientWidth` and `.parentElement.clientHeight`) of the parent element, finds the smaller one and sizes the canvas according to that by setting `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height`, but for some reason I don't understand this doesn't work - the canvas ends up too small and only resizes to the correct setting on a window resize. In this case, the parent element's size was determined by flexbox.

EDIT: the following code does *almost* what I am looking for. There is only one problem, which you can observe by:

- loading the page in a non-maximed window
- maximizing and un-maximizing that window.

The resulting layout is not the same as the original (directly after the load).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background: #404040;
        height: 100vh;
        min-width: 800px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
    main {
        background: yellow;
        flex: 0 1 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .sidepanel {
        background: blue;
        flex: 0.2 0.4 250px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .spacer {
        flex: 0.5 1 0;
    }
    #square {
        background: black;
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
<script type="module">
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#square')
    const parent = canvas.parentElement
    const setSquare = () => {
        const { clientWidth, clientHeight } = parent
        const L = Math.min(clientWidth, clientHeight)
        canvas.style.width = canvas.style.height = `${L}px`
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', setSquare)
    setSquare()
</script>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<section class="sidepanel">
</section>
<main>
    <canvas id="square"></canvas>
</main>
<section class="sidepanel">
</section>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use flexbox and maintain a 1:1 aspect ratio even though content is sized differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44009015/use-flexbox-and-maintain-a-11-aspect-ratio-even-though-content-is-sized-differe)